# Why is my basic rumor simulation program not working?

Tags: java

My assignment

[image]

I have been tasked with attempting to code this program in Java. I've coded a program I think should work, but no matter what I input as the argument it says everyone has heard the rumor in every situation. I think it has something to do with skipping my while loops and me miswriting something else later on...? I'm completely lost, and because my attempts to troubleshoot what is being executed and what isn't have been failing I don't really know how to fix it. My attempt at coding the problem is below. I've tried to put in a lot of notes to help anyone trying to help me follow along, though I'm not sure if I have out everything down in the right etiquette; sorry if I messed up!

```
public class ProgrammingProblem1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    int people = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) ;
    //Obtains how many people not including Alice are at the party

    boolean[] guests;

    double averageheard = 0.0;
    // This double will be used at the end to determine on average how many people heard the rumor.

    double totalheard = 0.0;
    // This double is used to help calculate how many people heard the rumor over all the iterations. Keeps track of the total people who knew the rumor throughout the permutations.

    double percentsuccess = 0.0;
    // This double will be used at the end to determine the percent of how many times the rumor was heard by everyone against how many loops there were.

    double rumorsuccess = 0;
    // This keeps track of how many times the rumor went all the way around.

    double rumorfail = 0;
    // This keeps track of how many time the rumor did not make it all the way around.

    guests = new boolean[people];
    //Fills the array with as many slots as there are people at the party. Guests is the array that stores if someone has heard the rumor or not.

    int runtime = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
        // Guests is to figure out how many guests besides Alice are at the party and set them in an array, and Runtime is to figure out how many simulations you are meant to run.

    if (people < 1 || runtime < 0){
    //This is to check if the arguments were entered correctly.

        System.out.println("You entered the arguments incorrectly. The amount of people at the party besides Alice must be at least two and the simulation must be run at least once.");
    
    }else {

        for ( int i = 0; i < runtime ; i++) {
        // This is for doing however many iterations through are desired.

            int heard = 0;
            // This variable will be used at the end to determine if everyone has heard the rumor.

            int current = 0 ;
            // This ensures that we start with our first person ,"Bob", as the progintor of the rumor. Current is whoever is currently telling the rumor to someone else.
            
            for (int l = 0; l < people; l++){

                guests[l] = false; }

                

            guests[0] = true ;
            // This ensures that Bob already knows the rumor.
            
            int next = (int)(Math.random() * people) ;
            // This randomly selects the first person Bob asks about it. Next is the person we are telling the rumor to

            while (current == next) {
                // This makes sure that the guest we are doing isn't talking to themselves
    
                    next = (int)(Math.random() * people ); 
                }

            while ( !guests[next] ) {
            // This makes the loop go on until the canidate the person it would tell has already heard it
                
                guests[next] = true;
                // This line makes whoever was just told the rumor now knows the rumor

                int last = current;
                // This keeps track of who the last person who said the rumor was

                current = next;
                // This is making the person we just told the rumor to our new rumor teller.

                next = (int)(Math.random() * people);
                // This finds a new person to be told the rumor

                while (current == next || last == next ){
                // This ensures that the person we tell the rumor to next will not be the person telling the rumor to or the person who told them the rumor.

                    next = (int)(Math.random() * people); }
                
                }

            for ( int j = 0; j < people; ++j) {
             // This is to determine how many people heard the rumor before it was terminated.

                 if ( guests[j] == true){

                    heard = heard + 1;

                 }
             }

             if ( heard == people){
             //This if statement will add a counter to rumorsuccess if every person was told the rumor, and to rumorfail if everyone didn't hear it.
                    
                 rumorsuccess = rumorsuccess + 1;
            }

            else{

                rumorfail = rumorfail + 1; }

            totalheard = totalheard + heard;
            //This is to tally up how many people heard the rumor in total.

            }

        percentsuccess = (rumorsuccess / (rumorsuccess + rumorfail)) * 100 ;
        // This calculates the percent of times the rumor went all the way around to everyone

        averageheard = (totalheard / runtime) ;
        // This calculates the average amount of times the rumor made its way around

        System.out.println("Steven Mikels 20782");
        System.out.println("The amount of people in the room besides Alice are: " + people + ". The amount of times the simulation was run is: " + runtime);
        System.out.println("The rumor was heard by everyone in the room " + percentsuccess + " percent of the time. The average amount of people who heard the rumor was: " + averageheard); 
    
    }

}
```

}

EDIT 1: I have updated the code to accommodate my updating of the == related error. I have a few new issues now that the code calculates how many people heard on average correctly, though the percentage of times everyone has succeeded doesn't seem to be working. Entering "3" and then any other number into the command line correctly gives 100% of times gone through everyone hears it. Unfortunately, entering any number of people greater than 3 means the code have 0% chance to go all the way around, which is false. Additionally, entering "2" as the first number seems to make the program stall out command prompt. After some testing, it seems the variable rumorfail and rumorsuccess are always equal to each other.

EDIT 2: I'm fairly certain that I've managed to fix my problem; the variables rumorfail and rumorsuccess needed to be a double! It was rounding the number up or down, resulting in the 0% or 100% marks. Unfortunately, I'm still have an issue where my program won't allow two to be the amount of people or else it freaks out. I'm testing for more reasons on why that may be right now, but didn't want people working on the other issue since it is already solved! Strangely, 0 executes the statement correctly and prints that an invalid number has been inputted, but 1 shares the same problem that 2 did.

Comment: What are you passing for the args?

Comment: And `while ( guests[next] = false )` isn't doing what you think. Instead just do `while ( !guests[next])`, and similar for `guests[j] = true `

Comment: Adding to what  @cricket_007 said, you need to use logical == for comparision if you want to use explicit comparision. That is , while ( guests[next] == false )

Comment: I've adjusted the while loops to your suggested format @cricket_007 (I wasn't entirely sure how to switch the guests[j] if statement one so I took Hari's advice and added another equals sign) and this is getting me real data! PROGRESS! Imputing "10 10" into the command prompt gets me a number between 4 and 5, though it does says it never managed to tell everyone the rumor. After testing for ten thousand permutations, it never managed to go all the way around which seems... Fishy to say the least. Also imputing "2 2" into the command prompt doesn't output anything, and seems be stuck executing.

Comment: I've enhanced my explanation some, and am doing further testing to try and add even more. @cricket_007 . Also if pinging people like this is impolite on this website, just tell me and I'll try to stick to using them only when a new development happens.

Comment: I've fixed the biggest chunk of my problem, and have edited the problem acourding. I still have a problem where there cannot only be 2 people, however.

Comment: FWIW, it would be useful to learn about the debugging features of an IDE of your choice. Or add more print statements. More info - https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat i see a couple typos:
Youre while statement
`while ( guests[next] = false ) {` is missing a "="
it should be written like this `guests[next] == false` or `!guests[next]`
you also did the same thing in this if statement `if ( guests[j] = true){`
it should be `guests[j] == true`
The reason for this extra "=" is that "==" is the comparing operator, and "=" is the operator to set something equal to, so when you do `if(x=1)` your checking wheter not x CAN be set equal to 1, not if it is equal to 1;
Otherwise your code looks like it would run and calculate, just fix these syntax errors.

Comment: I've done the == sign edits and updated my page according. Unfortunately, I seem to have made a logical error somewhere into being able to actually reach every person. Even when making the amount of people four, I still always get 0% times completed even when doing as many as a thousand iterations. Additionally my program will stall command prompt if I enter "2 2" into the command prompt line; perhaps they are related?